# ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult download file in jquery ajax

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file

From my view I make a GET call with ajax jquery to my controller, which returns a FileContentResult this is an excel file what it returns. The file is created instantly, it is not on the server, I cannot pass a url to download the file since it does not exist.

It works for me if I return the FileContentResult from the controller, but on the page the user does not know when the download will finish or if it continues to download, I need to know if the download is still in progress and if the download has finished. I can't show a popup because I don't know if the download continues, I only know that the file has been downloaded when I see it in my browser downloaded.

Controller code:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("MyExcel");
string contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.ContentType = contentType;
Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyExcel.xlsx");
return File(Utils.XLS(table), contentType, "MyExcel.xlsx");

**Utils.XLS(table):** this function return byte[] from table
```

The excel file is generated correctly, I have checked.

When the call Ajax is finished I retrieve the data and do the following:

```
$.get(url, function (data, status, xhr) {
    var contentType = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-Type");
    var filename = xhr.getResponseHeader("Content-disposition");
    filename = filename.substring(filename.lastIndexOf("=") + 1);
    var blob = new Blob([data], {
             type: contentType
    );
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.download = filename;
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
});
```

The excel file downloads successfully but appears corrupted and does not contain any information inside.
I have tried many ways that I have been finding but none have worked for me.

**Solution**

In the request of the ajax request you have to add the responsetype 'arrayBuffer'

```
var xhrOverride = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhrOverride.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

$.ajax({
     url: url,
     method: 'POST',
     xhr: function () {
          return xhrOverride;
     }
}).done(function (data, status, xhr) { 
   //request correct
}
```

Comment: you can find answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4545311/download-a-file-by-jquery-ajax)

Comment: don't add the answer as part of your question. This is a Q&A site, it follows a specific format. If you found the answer, add it in the Answers section below, separately. That way people can vote on the answer specifically, and it will show in search results etc. See also [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) Thanks.

Comment: I do not have 15 of reputation, according to the link that you gave me I need 15 of reputation to be able to add my own answer to my question. That is why I have added my own answer to the question.